# php url redirect to home page

Tags: php, redirect

Well, I don't know if I made a title properly but I've got a lil php script out there and I am wondering if there might be possibility when user go to this url:

```
siteurl.com/index.php?token=J55OSGTTk3W7mRcuq54006w7ROv
```

to get automatically only /index.php without the content that he copy/pasted in this case

```
?token=J55OSGTTk3W7mRcuq54006w7ROv
```

Hope it is possible. Cheers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. Issue a `Location` header and use **[`parse_url()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php)** to get the parts you need.

```
$url      = "http://siteurl.com/index.php?token=J55OSGTTk3W7mRcuq54006w7ROv";
$parsed   = parse_url($url);
$redirect = $parsed["scheme"] . "://" . $parsed["host"] . $parsed["path"];
header("Location: $redirect");
```

Comment: Time to read what these stuff is :) ! No knowledge in php. Thanks!
I'll check back if I succeed to make this work!

Comment: this actually works perfectly. But theres small problem. I've added your code (thanks for that) but I have an error message.

The webpage at http://myurl.com has resulted in too many redirects. Clearing your cookies for this site or allowing third-party cookies may fix the problem. If not, it is possibly a server configuration issue and not a problem with your computer.

Comment: @NenaddvL: Yes well, the redirect header would happen every single time, you need to check to make sure the $_GET array is empty of `token`, and if not, issue the location header.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe `explode($url,"?")[0]`. If there's no question mark, then it should return an array of length one. If there is, you'll only get everything before the '?'.